# Calling a method in componentWillReceiveProps shows values of stale props

Tags: reactjs

I'm aware that `componentWillRecieveProps` has been deprecated already in React 16+ and also aware that React's reconciliation system is somewhat async on most occasions and I think it is because of that I'm seeing this behavior here. I just want a confirmation (or solution) to understand if my understanding is correct.

I have the following `Child` component:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Child extends PureComponent {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("--nextprops--");
    console.log(nextProps);
    this.callMe();
  }

  callMe() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    console.log("--callme--", data);
    return <div>{data}</div>;
  }

  render() {
    console.log("--render--");
    return this.callMe();
  }
}
```

and this is being used in this `Parent` component.

```
class App extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeMe = this.changeMe.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      data: "ok"
    };
  }
  changeMe() {
    const dat = ["ok", "bye"];
    const randomize = parseInt(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 0 : 1);
    this.setState({
      data: dat[randomize]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.changeMe}> randomize </button>
        <Child data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/ojo43r3xw9?expanddevtools=1

If you run the above app and start clicking on the `button` then you'll notice that the behavior is as expected however, if you check the console you'll notice that right above `--render--`, `--callme--` is consoling old prop `data` and right after it we see `--callme--` with the expected data.

Now, you might just tell me to set a `state` in `Child` component and then use `this.setState` in `componentWillRecieveProps` with `this.callMe` as a callback handler - but that's besides the point.

The thing I'm curious about is that when invoking `callMe` immediately in `componentWillReceiveProps` is there no guarantee that `props` will be updated with `nextProps`' value?
The only solution I can think of right now is to pass the `nextProps` as an argument to `callMe` method and get the data from there but I was trying to avoid that and just use `this.props` to check for value of props.

I did try looking in docs if this behavior was mentioned but I couldn't find it or maybe I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: I have a hard time seeing why you would ever have to do this. `changeMe()` is called on each re-render anyways, so the point of calling it when props change is redundant. Anyways I'm fairly certain `componentWillReceiveProps` is called before new props are set to the component. As per the docs you are recommended to compare nextProps with current props and only then invoke whatever function. Which leads me to believe that this.props will not contain the new values

Comment: @Tsuni I should have avoided putting `this.callMe()` in `render` but that was just done just so that I can display something on the screen. The reason I would want this is because I'm trying to use `d3` which binds to a DOM ref and would like the d3 to update/re-render the data that it's controlling without having `react` to re-render everytime there's new data. Also, you're right about adding checks in `componentWillReceiveProps` but felt that it was irrelevant in the point that I was trying to make here.

Comment: Maybe `shouldComponentUpdate` would suit you better then? At least you got the possibility to avoid re-rendering when props update

Comment: That's true but I was wanting to know more about how/when react updates the `props` after we pass new props to it. It doesn't look like it does that immediately (as seen in callMe when calling it from `componentWillReceiveProps`) but the new props do get updated on `callMethod` from `render` method however.

Comment: when componentWillReceiveProps is called, this.props would be old props, when the component renders, it will have the updated props. render would always have the latest props, and cWRP is a way to check the next props and react to it, so this.props would only be updated after this method ends. In this case, you call a function before this method finishes and hence you would see the old props